# Purpose of swt-win32-3064.dll

Tags: dll

Can anyone tell me the usage of **swt-win32-3064.dll**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a dll required to run the eclipse [Standard Widget Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) on windows. SWT is a GUI library which uses native GUI libraries on various platforms and therefore give true native look and feel to Java applications.